# How are floats and doubles interpreted by the compiler and eventually represented in memory?

Tags: c, assembly, memory, architecture

For example : a simple definition of a float number in C , 
float x =1.375

how can we write this in assembly and how does it get mapped to the data memory ?

An example of doing operations on floats, and storing the values in the memory (in PIC assembly) to get a sense of how are we dealing with floats on a level that's closer to the hardware.

Comment: On what architecture? "Assembly language" is different for every type of CPU.

Comment: Many implementations use [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). A nice picture for a 32-bit float can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32).

Comment: Short answer: 1.375 is represented internally as 11 (binary 1011) times 2 to the -3, which works out to binary 1.011.

Comment: There are various floating point formats, so the binary value can vary.  Then there are storage differences based on architecture, endianness being the first one.  so there is no one issue, you need to be more specific.

Comment: what does assembly language have to do with this?  assembly is defined by the assembler, the program that reads it and you can have more than one assembly language per target instruction set, so "it varies" just like the exact syntax can vary across other languages.  ideally you have an assembler that allows the syntax 1.375 as an initializer to what we would assume is a 32 bit storage location, assembly doesnt care about float vs a hole in the wall so other than initialization or syntax, to distinguish base 2, 8, 10, 16, float, ascii, it shouldnt care.

Comment: say PIC assembly .

Comment: I don't think PIC has built-in support for floating point, so a simple ADD that takes two floats is dozens of lines of PIC assembly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core idea of floating-point representations, is that a number `x` is written as `m*b^e` where `m` is a **mantissa** or fractional part, `b` is a **base**, and `e` is an **exponent**.

e.g.

```
0.375 = 1.5*(2^(-2))
```

---

### The IEEE-754 floating-point standard

The IEEE-754 floating-point standard is a standard for representing and manipulating floating-point quantities that is followed by all modern computer systems. It defines several standard representations of floating-point numbers, all of which have the following basic pattern (the specific layout here is for 32-bit floats):

[image]

The bit numbers are counting from the least-significant bit. The **first bit is the sign** (0 for positive, 1 for negative). The **following 8 bits are the exponent** in excess-127 binary notation; this means that the binary pattern `01111111 = 127` represents an exponent of 0, `1000000 = 128`, represents 1, `01111110 = 126` represents -1, and so forth. The **mantissa fits in the remaining 24 bits**, with its leading 1 stripped off as described above.

Certain numbers have a special representation. Because 0 cannot be represented in the standard form (there is no 1 before the decimal point), it is given the special representation `0 00000000 00000000000000000000000`. (There is also a `-0 = 1 00000000 00000000000000000000000`, which looks equal to +0 but prints differently.) Numbers with exponents of `11111111 = 255 = 2128` represent non-numeric quantities such as **not a number** (`NaN`), returned by operations like (0.0/0.0) and positive or negative infinity.

example:

```
     0 =                        0 = 0 00000000 00000000000000000000000
    -0 =                       -0 = 1 00000000 00000000000000000000000
 0.125 =                    0.125 = 0 01111100 00000000000000000000000
  0.25 =                     0.25 = 0 01111101 00000000000000000000000
   0.5 =                      0.5 = 0 01111110 00000000000000000000000
     1 =                        1 = 0 01111111 00000000000000000000000
     2 =                        2 = 0 10000000 00000000000000000000000
     4 =                        4 = 0 10000001 00000000000000000000000
     8 =                        8 = 0 10000010 00000000000000000000000
 0.375 =                    0.375 = 0 01111101 10000000000000000000000
  0.75 =                     0.75 = 0 01111110 10000000000000000000000
   1.5 =                      1.5 = 0 01111111 10000000000000000000000
     3 =                        3 = 0 10000000 10000000000000000000000
     6 =                        6 = 0 10000001 10000000000000000000000
   0.1 =      0.10000000149011612 = 0 01111011 10011001100110011001101
   0.2 =      0.20000000298023224 = 0 01111100 10011001100110011001101
   0.4 =      0.40000000596046448 = 0 01111101 10011001100110011001101
   0.8 =      0.80000001192092896 = 0 01111110 10011001100110011001101
 1e+12 =             999999995904 = 0 10100110 11010001101010010100101
 1e+24 =   1.0000000138484279e+24 = 0 11001110 10100111100001000011100
 1e+36 =   9.9999996169031625e+35 = 0 11110110 10000001001011111001110
   inf =                      inf = 0 11111111 00000000000000000000000
  -inf =                     -inf = 1 11111111 00000000000000000000000
   nan =                      nan = 0 11111111 10000000000000000000000
```

For a **64-bit double**, the size of both the exponent and mantissa are larger:

- signed - 1
- exponent - 11
- mantissa - 52

**Intel processors** internally use an even larger 80-bit floating-point format for all operations:

- signed - 1
- exponent - 15
- mantissa - 64

**[SOURCE](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)FloatingPoint.html)**

Comment: Thank you, but I need an example of doing operations on floats in PIC assembly to get a sense of how are we dealing with floats on a level that's closer to the hardware.

Comment: I answered about the representation of `floats`, operations on them will need another answer.

Comment: @Riolite: most CPU architectures have an FPU built-in, so adding the mantissas and then re-normalizing by shifting the mantissa left/right while incrementing / decrementing the exponent is done in hardware.  There are open source software floating point implementations, though; google that if you're curious or want some code you can use on PIC.  It's probably easier to understand the concepts by looking at C or asm for a 32-bit platform first, though, before you look at code for PIC that has to use extended-precision to deal with a 23-bit mantissa.

Comment: Also, this answer is assuming IEEE754.  ISO C doesn't guarantee that; it's possible that a software floating-point implementation might do something different, especially when targeting an architecture that never has a hardware FPU.

Comment: And BTW, Wikipedia has very good articles on IEEE FP, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that article of Wikipedia, that's quite useful.

Comment: @Riolite the question is, why do you want C-like `float` type... without the HW FPU it's actually a bit questionable choice, the IEEE-754 encoding is excellent compromise between various options to provide probably the most universal way of floating point values encoding, which means that it lacks in every specialization.. it's not very accurate, it doesn't cover huge range (only very big) and it's granularity is not fixed (values outward from 0 are more sparse next to each other), each of this perks can be covered better by different type of encoding. If you have FPU, main advantage is speed.